# Mac OS X Custom Dock Application

Tags: objective-c, macos

I  would like to know how to create a custom dock application in Mac OS X like Dockshelf or uBar:

http://www.thealchemistguild.com/dockshelf/

https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar

Very importantly, this custom Dock should be visible when other applications go full screen (like the native OS X Dock).

I cannot find this information anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the dock effect, create a very thin (say for example 2px wide), fully-transparent window with no decorations as your application's main window and fix it to the edge of the desktop (you need to take special care if the user has more than one screen). When the mouse cursor hovers towards that area, reveal your primary user interface (e.g. your custom *dock*).

To hide the menu bar (like the Dock) application, call `NSApplication  setPresentationOptions:` with `NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar`.

Finally to hide the icon call `TransformProcessType` with `kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication`.

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
```

And now you have an application that *docks* to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a semi-transparent window with level of (NSScreenSaverWindowLevel-1) so it's on top of all applications. But when another application like Safari goes full screen, it has its own Space and my dock is no longer visible. But in Dockshelf, it is still visible in another applications full-screen Space. Do you know what setting gives it that special "Dock" status?

Comment: @Cliff You might want to look at `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces`. Btw, the official Dock doesn't show if an app is full screen. It wouldn't even come out of hiding.